# Flutter - How to change the Color class' value that placed inside a custom widget?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-widget

I'd like to create a widget that I'll use it a lot of times, so I don't have to create it manully.

here's what I've built:

```
    Widget keyWidget(String keyNumber, String keyName) {
          return Container(
              width: 100.0,
              height: 50.0,
              color: Colors.red, //How I change the color's value? (Colors.{this_one})?
              child: FlatButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  final player = AudioCache();
                  player.play('key$keyNumber.mp3');
                },
                child: Text('$keyName'),
              ),
            );
}
```

How do I change the color's value (`color: Colors.{this_one},`) so I could set it in the `keyWidget` properties?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass your `Color` as argument in your `keyWidget()` method

Try this way

```
 Widget keyWidget(String keyNumber, String keyName,Color mColor) {
          return Container(
              width: 100.0,
              height: 50.0,
              color: mColor, //How I change the color's value? (Colors.{this_one})?
              child: FlatButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  final player = AudioCache();
                  player.play('key$keyNumber.mp3');
                },
                child: Text('$keyName'),
              ),
            );
}
```

Now you can call this method like this.

```
keyWidget('keyNumber','keyName',Colors.red);
keyWidget('keyNumber','keyName',Colors.pink);
keyWidget('keyNumber','keyName',Color(0xffACACAC));
```

You can also make `Color` parameter optional

**SAMPLE CODE**

```
Widget keyWidget(String keyNumber, String keyName,{ mColor=Colors.red}) {
    return Container(
      width: 100.0,
      height: 50.0,
      color: mColor, //How I change the color's value? (Colors.{this_one})?
      child: FlatButton(
        onPressed: () {
          final player = AudioCache();
          player.play('key$keyNumber.mp3');
        },
        child: Text('$keyName'),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Now you can call this method like this.

```
keyWidget('keyNumber', 'keyName');
keyWidget('keyNumber', 'keyName',mColor:  Colors.accents);
```